# .zshrc:3: parse error near `>' when i open terminal on mac

Tags: flutter, macos, terminal, zshrc

i have error when i open my macOS Monterey 12.3.1 terminal after installing flutter like this :

```
 Last login: Sat May 14 10:49:04 on console
/Users/malela/.zshrc:3: parse error near `>'
malela@galihs-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

and here my .zshrc file

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/FlutterDev/flutter/bin"

 >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/malela/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/malela/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/malela/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/malela/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

export
PATH=/Users/malela/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/malela/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin
```

after that i can't use brew syntaks like this

```
Last login: Sat May 14 10:50:20 on ttys000
/Users/malela/.zshrc:3: parse error near `>'
malela@galihs-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew
zsh: command not found: brew
malela@galihs-MacBook-Pro ~ % '
```

The question is how to fix that?
Thank you

Comment: You've forgotten the `#` at the start of the conda comment.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
>>> conda initialize >>>
```

To

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
```

Comment: Thanks you but it show another error /Users/malela/.zshrc:20: parse error near `\n'

Comment: What on earth did you use to edit that file?

Comment: @GalihMalelaDamaraji  Your question  was about `.zshrc:3: parse error near '>'` and now you have your answer. Please don't "leech" by asking other questions.